# Python:IndexError: list index out of range in python

Tags: python-2.7

So, i'm just a noob when it comes to programming especially python. I have a list holding all the variable names that i'm using in my program:

```
dList=['market_a','market_b','market_c','market_d','market_e','market_f','market_g']
```

**What i want to do is remove all these objects from memory** i.e., this is what i believe needs to be done:

```
del market_a,market_b,market_c,market_d,market_e,market_f,market_g
market_a=market_b=market_c=market_d=market_e=market_f=market_g= None
```

I was trying to `del` the objects by doing something like this:

```
for index in (len(dList):
   del dList[index]
```

But i'm getting this error.

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can somebody please help me with this? Also can somebody please tell me how i can do `market_a=market_b=market_c=market_d=market_e=market_f=market_g= None`from `dList`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To that person who down voted this question: atleast be so kind as to tell me what is wrong with my question man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not recommending that you do this (see below for a dictionary based solution), however, you can use the `exec` statement to assign `None` to the variables:

```
dList = ['market_a', 'market_b', 'market_c', 'market_d', 'market_e', 'market_f', 'market_g']

for var in dList:
    exec '{} = None'.format(var)
```

You can also explicitly call `del` on the variable:

```
for var in dList:
    exec 'del {}'.format(var)
    # exec '{} = None'.format(var)
```

although this is not usually required because, if the object to which a variable name was bound has no other references to it, rebinding the variable name results in the original object being eligible for garbage collection and so it will eventually be removed from memory.

---

In general it makes little sense to store a list of variable names: if the variables are static, that is, known to your code at "compile" time, then you already know what they are called and can simply refer to them by name in your code.

If the variables are dynamic then you'd be better off using a dictionary to associate the names with values. Treat the entries in the dictionary as your variables.

```
markets = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6, 'g': 7}

# to access a "variable"
>>> markets['a']
1

# to modify a "variable"
>>> markets['a'] += 100
>>> markets['a']
101
```

To delete them all you can simply delete the dictionary:

```
del markets
```

or rebind it to an empty dictionary:

```
markets = {}
```

Assuming that there is no other reference to the objects stored as values in the dictionary, this will make these objects available for garbage collection, effectively deleting them from memory.

Or you can delete specific keys:

```
# to delete a specific "variable"
del markets['a']
```

Unless it is required by your algorithms there's no need to assign `None`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But as it is, my program actually requires me to assign everything as `None` before performing `del`. Can u suggest a way to do that also?

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your help and yes the variables are dynamic. I guess i would have to change the entire code so that the variable names are getting assigned to a dict.

Comment: @Christian: I've updated my answer to show how you could do it with the `exec` statement.

Comment: Please dont take any offense. I understand that your solution is a valid one. But since @HulkinBrain's solution would be easier for me to implement, i will be voting his answer. Still thanks a lot for your effort

Comment: Thank you for enlightening me regarding HulkinBrain's response.

Answer (score 0):

As you delete your array is getting smaller, therefore the index is no longer correct.

You can try this:

```
while dList:
   del dList[0]
```

Just a note when the array is empty, it will evaluate to False.

Comment: thanks for ur suggestion. Also can u help me with assigning all the variables with `None`. I have to do that before performing `del`.

Comment: just do dList[0] = None before the del statement

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above as you remove items the array gets smaller so a for loop is probably not the best solution. To me it looks like you are trying to accomplish 2 tasks: shrink the array and physically delete the variables:

```
while dList:
    var = dList.pop(0)
    exec('del {0}'.format(var))
```

Consider using the pop() method which will shrink your array and then using the exec() method to delete the variable from memory by passing in the variable name and instead of deleting the string deleting the actual variable instance.